# How to use copy_if for maps

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, copy

I'm trying to copy a map (i want to copy _citymap to _the_cities) using copy_if.
this is my code:

```
std::map <string, pair <float,float>> _citymap;

copy_if(_citymap.begin(),_citymap.end(),
std::inserter(_the_cities,_the_cities.end()),
[this](decltype(_citymap)::value_type const &kv_pair) {
return (Manhattan_Distance(kv_pair.second));});
```

the function Manhattan_Distance is a bool function:

`bool Search:: Manhattan_Distance (const pair <float, float> &the_pair)
    {
     return (_radius >= fabs(_citymap[_city].first-the_pair.first) +

         fabs(_citymap[_city].second-the_pair.second));
    }`

The errors I get:

1. error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value
2. IntelliSense: class "std::map (std::string, std::pair(float, float), std::less(std::string), std::allocator(std::pair(const std::string, std::pair(float, float>>>>" has no member "second"
3. error C2039: 'second' : is not a member of 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copy_if` requires the predicate take an argument of the type obtained by dereferencing the iterator (or something implicitly convertible from that type), in this case `map::value_type`, which is an `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>`. Change your lambda expression to:

```
[](decltype(_citymap)::value_type const& kv_pair) {
    return Manhattan_Distance(kv_pair.second);
}
```

I'm assuming your `Manhattan_Distance()` function looks like this:

```
bool Manhattan_Distance(std::pair<float, float> const& the_pair)
{ return /* ... */; }
```

With C++14 you can even leave the `decltype(...)` part out of the argument type:

```
[](auto const& kv_pair) {
    return Manhattan_Distance(kv_pair.second);
}
```

Comment: @user3617423 Is `Manhattan_Distance` itself a lambda? If so, you need to capture it - the `copy_if` predicate should be `[Manhattan_Distance](decltype(...)...`. If that's not the case, the please update the question showing the definition of `Manhattan_Distance`, and where it's defined in relation to the call to `copy_if`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
this is the function:  
`bool Search:: Manhattan_Distance (const pair <float, float> &the_pair)
{
 return (_radius >= fabs(_citymap[_city].first-the_pair.first) + fabs(_citymap[_city].second-the_pair.second));
 
}`

Comment: @user3617423 It looks like `Manhattan_Distance` is a non-static member function of the `Search` class. Assuming the `copy_if` call is happening in another member of the same class, you need to capture the `this` pointer to be able to invoke other member functions. So your lambda should be `[this](decltype(...)...`

Comment: @user3617423 Is it just Intellisense errors, or are you getting compiler errors too (error messages with *Cxxx* identifiers)? If it's the former you can ignore them. Otherwise you're going to have to post more code, and the error messages from the compiler. Indicate what lines the errors are occurring at.

Comment: @user3617423 Try explicitly specifying the return type for the lambda `[this](decltype(_citymap)::value_type const &kv_pair) -> bool {...}`. I don't know the cause of the error C2039 is because I don't know what line it's happening on.

Comment: It refers to `return (Manhattan_Distance(kv_pair.second));});`

Comment: @user3617423 [That should work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15009991b4e98c05). Try to compile the linked example, if that works, keeping adding more code to `Manhattan_Distance` so that it looks like your actual function, until something breaks. If you still can't figure it out, I'd say it's time to post a new question. Use my example as a starting point.